# How do I refer a state value in the value attribute of the input field value={ house.room} For e.g., value={this.state.inputText}. Thanks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I'm using an existing web application. I am getting the input value as {house.room} and not able to set a state value for this. Please let me know how to apply "this.state" for this or any other format to solve this For e.g., I am able to do this
this.setState({ room: this.props.house.room }); .

Note : The problem is the backspace or del button doestnot remove the value entered into the input field.

Thanks

Comment: Use `<input defaultValue={house.room} />` instead if `<input value={house.room} />`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone !
Need to mention "this.state.room" in the input Value and check the prev state using the componentDidUpdate then "this.setState" here and also finally "this.setState" during the event change. Thanks